# Giving ownership and permission to non-root user from inside script

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, non-root-user

I have an automated process that installs a script on an Ubuntu 20.04 server as `root`, and then runs it, as `root`.

Inside the script, I create a directory, say, `foobaz` and install an executable in that directory. The thing is, come runtime, the executable needs to be owned by and executed by the `ubuntu` (non-root) user.

So I need a way to essentially, as `root`, do:

```
# inside the bash script:
mkdir foobar
curl "https://myapp-deploys.example.com/myapp.exe" -o foobar/myapp.exe
cd foobar
./myapp.exe
```

But somehow I need the `ubuntu` user to own and be the user that runs `myapp.exe`. Even when the script is being ran *as `root`*. **How can I do this?**

Comment: Maybe `chown ubuntu ./myapp.exe` and `sudo -u ubuntu ./myapp.exe`. Why do you run the script as `root` and not as `ubuntu`?

Comment: This is an automated process that installs and runs the script, and forces me to use `root`. But the app was developed with the requirement as being ran as non-root.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all information to the question. Add more details about the automated process, how exactly the script is installed and run. You can use `sudo` to run a command or script as a different user.